# how to fix this issue ? cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.2) ... error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'

Tags: numpy, opencv, operating-system, rotation, data-augmentation

I am trying to do rotation on multiple images in a folder but I am having this error when I put values of fx, fy greater than 0.2 in the resize function
(**cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.2) ... error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'**)

Although, when I try to rotate a single image and put values of fx and fy equal to 0.5, it works perfectly fine.

Is there a way to fix this issue because it is very hectic to augment images one by one? Plus the multiple images which are rotated by the code attached here, with fx and fy values equal to 0.2, have undesirable dimensions i.e the photos are very small and their quality is also reduced.

the part of code for rotation of multiple images is given below:

```
for imag in os.listdir(source_folder):
img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(source_folder,imag))
img = cv2.resize(img, (0,0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)
width = img.shape[1]
height =  img.shape[0]
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((width/2,height/2),5,1.0)
rotated_img = cv2.warpAffine(img,M,(img.shape[1],img.shape[0]))
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(destination_right_folder, "v4rl" + str(a) + '.jpg') , rotated_img)
#cv2.imshow("rotated_right",rotated_img)
#cv2.waitKey(0)
a += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a check after you read the image to see if it is None:

```
img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(source_folder,imag))
if img is None: continue
```

The error is happening when you call the cv2.resize() function. Maybe files are being read that are not images.

Comment: This helped. I deleted an extra file which was not an image and now the code works fine